# What is reason for automatic file lock symbol or automatic binary file conversion?

Tags: files, lock, binary

1. A brief description of the problem:
   Folders in a pendrive got converted to binary or lock symbol appeared on them in ubuntu: 
   (a.) when deleting inner folders (or)
   (b.) while right click and checking permissions.
   NOTE: 
   My folder had permissions rwx set for all. And pendrive was affected by virus when it was inserted into other os. (other os can be or cannot be windows.). After inserting into that OS, pendrive was containing .Ink files as well apart from my data.

Initial snapshot
[snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3LhH.jpg),
Right click to check the properties 
[snapshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDEaa.jpg),
File converted to binary, (inner folders also were converted to binary)
[snapshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xoOJ.jpg),
Some other time File displayed lock symbol on it.
[snapshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgkNX.jpg)

2. This is my observation on some sample folder created by me. When I tried to change the permissions of the outer folder and removed execute permissions for all, inner folder got converted to binary type.

demo(folder)/data(folder)/file(file)
all have rwx set for them for all types of users
removed x permission to all.
changing permissions in terminal
[Snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtj1n.png)
gui snapshot of inner folder
[Snapshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyXnk.png)

If my assunmption is correct that in 1 their permissions have really changed then why did this even happen because I did not change the permissions, I just checked their properties or deleted some folders?

Or if my asssumption is wrong then how could it have been possible for folders to get automatically converted to binary or even lock symbol appear on them?

Ubuntu version:16.04 lts
I have asked a question but no answer [Pendrive automatically deleted files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995729/pendrive-automatically-deleted-files) but now I have included some of the observation here. Please try to answer it. Please see it is not the same question.

Comment: It looks like your pen drive is encrypted possibly by malware when it was inserted into the other OS.

Comment: pendrive is affected by virus. But all this behaviour mentioned above happened in ubuntu. I am asking why did such a behaviour happened in ubuntu.